# azure deployment: no package.json file in site/wwwroot

Tags: node.js, azure

When I try to open my Azure NodeJS React web app in Chrome, I get the following error:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm start
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/package.json
```

This checks out when I examine the contents of /site/wwwroot in the Azure SSH:

```
_del_node_modules
asset-manifest.json
b
favicon.ico
index.html
logo192.png
logo512.png
manifest.json
oryx-appinsightsloader.js
package-lock.json
precache-manifest.6794c2e4defba13a31dcee7cae67859b.js
precache-manifest.705c77ad34ded94d21baca064fa569aa.js
precache-manifest.730dd540546e78da1c3ebb04036e733d.js
precache-manifest.9980bb9186e0ebd2771eff926887f432.js
precache-manifest.9a518a34a27fad9a357b7c78cdfbb7e8.js
precache-manifest.9c65ce33aab3813a0f162cf91b74c0f4.js
precache-manifest.ac183c8385a56a732a8286d5f2d8fa64.js
precache-manifest.b8756a719b957537ff5eb2ede103962d.js
precache-manifest.cbb7b5b3cc0bfbf94c161143ff651d3b.js
precache-manifest.e58827ccfca6115bc9268d09a7361ddd.js
robots.txt
service-worker.js
static
web.config
```

My build pipeline on Azure runs npm install and npm run build from the root directory, which is successful when run in VScode. The pipeline and release are successful. The outer structure of my directory tree in VScode looks like this:

```
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
├── schema.sql
├── server
└── src
```

So it seems like the `npm run build` is running successfully, creating a `build` folder that populates the `/site/wwwroot` folder. But Azure is expecting a `package.json` file. I tried running `npm init` in the `public` folder in VScode and also tried adding `npm init` to the Azure pipeline build tasks, but was getting the same error.

Also, not sure if this is related or not, but I added a `web.config` file in the `public` folder. When I look at that file in the Azure SSH, it looks like it can't be read properly:

```
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 1: !--: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 3: ?xml: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 4: configuration: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 5: system.webServer: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 6: handlers: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 7: add: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 8: /handlers: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 9: rewrite: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 10: rules: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 11: rule: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 12: match: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 13: action: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 14: /rule: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 15: rule: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 16: match: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 17: conditions: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 18: add: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 19: add: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 20: add: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 21: /conditions: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 22: action: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 23: /rule: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 24: /rules: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 25: /rewrite: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 26: /system.webServer: No such file or directory
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/home/site/wwwroot/web.config: line 27: `</configuration>'
```

Here's what it looks like in VScode:

```
<!-- tells azure to rewrite all urls as if they are pointing to root file-->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem (using windows). It was difficult to create the `package.json` - as it was not appearing after `npm init`. Preventing me from being able to install npm packages.

It helped me to:

```
type NUL > package.json
```

```
npm init -f
```

To get a actual valid package.json in place.

**My problem was encountered creating a Functions App in the Azure Portal**

Answer (score 0):

This error means you didn't copy package.json file to the output folder.

If you're using Typescript - update tsconfig.json with include: ["package.json"]

if you're using Js or any build tool - copy the file using any shell script.

You can also be using post-build script in package.json with the value

install-package > `npm install copyfiles`

update script section

```
"postbuild": "npx copyfiles -u 1 ./src/**/*.json ./dist -V"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

Go to `https://[yourappname].scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host` and run `npm install -g npm`, and then run `npm init` command under `home/site/wwwroot`.

**Original Answer:**

Do you select Linux as the Web App's Operating System? I meet the similar problem on linux, but it doesn't occur on Windows OS.

In theory, there is no `package.json`, just use `npm init` to create it. I can operate smoothly on Windows OS, but not on Linux. I am investigating.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Linux. Was having some issues starting an app service on Windows. I will follow your updated advice. PS I'm the same person from the other thread you were answering about this issue, and I believe this question is better formatted, so I'm going to delete the other question.

Comment: Here's your answer from the other thread for posterity:
`Can you offer the folder and files in the home/site/wwwroot?

It seems you don't have a package.json

Try to run npm init under home/site/wwwroot, it will create package.json automatically.

node_modules stores local environment information. You can create it manually.`

Comment: I don't understand how running these commands after SSHing into Azure's server will ultimately help me-- because wouldn't I then have to SSH into Azure's server and run them manually every time I update and redeploy?

Comment: This just asked me a lot of questions about what to put into creating a package.json file, what do we put into the answers?

Comment: The answer here also broke my App Service in that I can no longer ssh into it